# How to make cumuative range of sum

Tags: excel

I would like the sum the values in one cell into nearby cell cumulatively. It should sum the values,i used below code, but i needed for range of cells say A1 to A10 and cumulative result should be in B1 to B10. Sorry i am newbie

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Range("A1"), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
[B1] = [B1] + [A1]
```

End Sub

Comment: Please provide an [mcve] otherwise we won't be able to help you.

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* This is a site where programmers *write their own code* and share a ***specific* problem** after trying to solve it on their own. Be sure to check out the [tour] (you'll earn your 1st badge!) and see "[ask]", and also the [help/on-topic] for more information about what's on topic on this site.  If you have a *specific* problem with a certain section of your code, you can [edit] your post to share an **[mcve]** as well as sample data and some background info.  Here are some  [tips](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) from the site's top user. Good Luck!

Comment: Seems like more than adequate information to determine the problem and 3 to 5 times better than 90% of the questions I've looked at today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, discard the [A1] style addressing and forget you ever knew it existed.

Expand the Intersect range and deal with Target where Target may be more than a single cell.

Temporarily suspend event handling or the Worksheet_Change will attempt to run on top of itself when you change values in the worksheet.

Handle errors or you may be left with a stuck workbook.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If not Intersect(Range("A1:A10"), Target) is nothing then
        on error goto meh
        application.enableevents = false
        dim t as range
        for each t in Intersect(Range("A1:A10"), Target)
            t.offset(0, 1) = t.offset(0, 1) + t.value2
        next t
    end if

meh:
    application.enableevents = true
End Sub
```